# is a jpeg with a bogus huffman table recoverable?

Tags: jpeg

I have a JPEG that is un-openable in any program:

Opening in Ubuntu Image Viewer yields:

[image: could not load image. bogus huffman table definition]

Passing the photo through `convert` yields similar results:

```
$ convert corrupt.jpg out.jpg
convert.im6: Bogus Huffman table definition `corrupt.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/316.
convert.im6: no images defined `out.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

Running the photo through `exiftool` yields:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.46
File Name                       : corrupt.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 47 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:04:11 01:31:14-07:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:05:04 10:26:04-07:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:05:04 10:26:03-07:00
File Permissions                : r--------
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Comment                         : Y�.�.�..2..Q.Q.
Image Width                     : 640
Image Height                    : 480
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:2 (2 1)
Image Size                      : 640x480
```

Un-corrupted photos containing similar image contents average `45-48k`, so I reckon the photo data itself is inside this JPEG somewhere.

I hosted the photo on S3. You can download it w/ `wget`:

`wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/jordanarseno.com/corrupt.jpg`

I opened the file with `hexedit` and found the following:

- the photo contents outside of the first few hundred bytes is randomly distributed enough to suggest it contains an image. i.e. I'm not seeing consecutive streams of `0`'s of `F`'s.
- it does in-fact start with the `FF D8` file signature, as JPEGs ought to.
- the next two bytes are not `FF E0` or `FF E1` like the [list of file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) says should correspond to JPEGs or JFIFs. Instead it is`FF FE`. Which, is in the table, but is listed as:

> Byte-order mark for text file encoded in little-endian 16-bit Unicode
>   Transfer Format

- not long after the `FF FE`, I see bytes whose ascii representation is: `&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz`. Seems rather strange for a JPEG. What is this?
- likewise, the ASCII string `&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz` appears about 100 bytes later.
- `FF D9` (the JPEG terminator string) **is** in the file, but characters do appear after this terminator:

  **FF D9** 5C 72 78 E0 7C 94 CD B2 9C FF 00 C4 BF 53 C0 E7 FE 41 D3 9C FF 00 E3 95 7C F1 B6 92 5F 7A 2B EB 54 AF BF E6 30 FD A0 7F CC 3B 53 E9 FF 00 40 F9 FF 00 F8 8A 4D F7 08 30

Switching over to Windows and using JPEGsnoop yields:

```
JPEGsnoop 1.8.0 by Calvin Hass
  http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/
  -------------------------------------

  Filename: [C:\corrupt.jpg]
  Filesize: [47760] Bytes

Start Offset: 0x00000000
*** Marker: SOI (xFFD8) ***
  OFFSET: 0x00000000

*** Marker: COM (Comment) (xFFFE) ***
  OFFSET: 0x00000002
  Comment length = 36
    Comment=Y.Ò................à.....2..Q.Q...

*** Marker: DQT (xFFDB) ***
  Define a Quantization Table.
  OFFSET: 0x00000028
  Table length = 132
  ----
  Precision=8 bits
  Destination ID=0 (Luminance)
    DQT, Row #0:   3   2   2   3   4   7   9  10 
    DQT, Row #1:   2   2   2   3   4  10  10   9 
    DQT, Row #2:   2   2   3   4   7  10  12  10 
    DQT, Row #3:   2   3   4   5   9  15  14  11 
    DQT, Row #4:   3   4   6  10  12  19  18  13 
    DQT, Row #5:   4   6   9  11  14  18  19  16 
    DQT, Row #6:   8  11  13  15  18  21  21  17 
    DQT, Row #7:  12  16  16  17  19  17  18  17 
    Approx quality factor = 91.45 (scaling=17.09 variance=0.95)
  ----
  Precision=8 bits
  Destination ID=1 (Chrominance)
    DQT, Row #0:   3   3   4   8  17  17  17  17 
    DQT, Row #1:   3   4   4  11  17  17  17  17 
    DQT, Row #2:   4   4  10  17  17  17  17  17 
    DQT, Row #3:   8  11  17  17  17  17  17  17 
    DQT, Row #4:  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17 
    DQT, Row #5:  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17 
    DQT, Row #6:  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17 
    DQT, Row #7:  17  17  17  17  17  17  17  17 
    Approx quality factor = 91.44 (scaling=17.11 variance=0.19)

*** Marker: COM (Comment) (xFFFE) ***
  OFFSET: 0x000000AE
  Comment length = 5
    Comment=...

*** Marker: SOF0 (Baseline DCT) (xFFC0) ***
  OFFSET: 0x000000B5
  Frame header length = 17
  Precision = 8
  Number of Lines = 480
  Samples per Line = 640
  Image Size = 640 x 480
  Raw Image Orientation = Landscape
  Number of Img components = 3
    Component[1]: ID=0x01, Samp Fac=0x21 (Subsamp 1 x 1), Quant Tbl Sel=0x00 (Lum: Y)
    Component[2]: ID=0x02, Samp Fac=0x11 (Subsamp 2 x 1), Quant Tbl Sel=0x01 (Chrom: Cb)
    Component[3]: ID=0x03, Samp Fac=0x11 (Subsamp 2 x 1), Quant Tbl Sel=0x01 (Chrom: Cr)

*** Marker: DHT (Define Huffman Table) (xFFC4) ***
  OFFSET: 0x000000C8
  Huffman table length = 418
  ----
  Destination ID = 0
  Class = 0 (DC / Lossless Table)
    Codes of length 01 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 02 bits (001 total): 00 
    Codes of length 03 bits (005 total): 01 02 03 04 05 
    Codes of length 04 bits (001 total): 06 
    Codes of length 05 bits (001 total): 07 
    Codes of length 06 bits (001 total): 08 
    Codes of length 07 bits (001 total): 09 
    Codes of length 08 bits (001 total): 0A 
    Codes of length 09 bits (001 total): 0B 
    Codes of length 10 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 11 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 12 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 13 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 14 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 15 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 16 bits (000 total): 
    Total number of codes: 012

  ----
  Destination ID = 1
  Class = 0 (DC / Lossless Table)
    Codes of length 01 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 02 bits (003 total): 13 0E 0F 
    Codes of length 03 bits (001 total): 10 
    Codes of length 04 bits (001 total): 11 
    Codes of length 05 bits (001 total): 12 
    Codes of length 06 bits (001 total): 12 
    Codes of length 07 bits (012 total): 12 0B 0D 13 15 13 11 15 10 11 12 11 
    Codes of length 08 bits (016 total): 01 03 03 03 04 04 04 08 04 04 08 11 0B 0A 0B 11 

    Codes of length 09 bits (013 total): 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 
    Codes of length 10 bits (011 total): 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 
    Codes of length 11 bits (012 total): 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 01 
    Codes of length 12 bits (015 total): 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 
    Codes of length 13 bits (012 total): 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 10 00 02 01 03 03 
    Codes of length 14 bits (009 total): 02 04 03 05 05 04 04 00 00 
    Codes of length 15 bits (010 total): 01 7D 01 02 03 00 04 11 05 12 
    Codes of length 16 bits (014 total): 21 31 41 06 13 51 61 07 22 71 14 32 81 91 
    Total number of codes: 131

  ----
  Destination ID = 1
  Class = 10 (AC Table)
ERROR: Invalid DHT Class (10). Aborting DHT Load.

ERROR: Expected marker 0xFF, got 0x73 @ offset 0x0000026C. Consider using [Tools->Img Search Fwd/Rev].

*** Searching Compression Signatures ***

  Signature:           01FF5BA518B453CC8F224A4C85505196
  Signature (Rotated): 01D13AFD01FF0B6EC46EA4081D25BB4D
  File Offset:         0 bytes
  Chroma subsampling:  2x1
  EXIF Make/Model:     NONE
  EXIF Makernotes:     NONE
  EXIF Software:       NONE

  Searching Compression Signatures: (3347 built-in, 0 user(*) )

          EXIF.Make / Software        EXIF.Model                            Quality           Subsamp Match?
          -------------------------   -----------------------------------   ----------------  --------------
     CAM:[NIKON                    ] [NIKON D40                          ] [FINE            ] Yes              

  Based on the analysis of compression characteristics and EXIF metadata:

  ASSESSMENT: Class 1 - Image is processed/edited

  This may be a new software editor for the database.
  If this file is processed, and editor doesn't appear in list above,
  PLEASE ADD TO DATABASE with [Tools->Add Camera to DB]


*** Additional Info ***
NOTE: Data exists after EOF, range: 0x00000000-0x0000BA90 (47760 bytes)
```

As a last note, the `EXIF.Model` identified by JPEGSnoop is incorrect. This photo would have been taken with a `VC0706 UART Model: LCF - 23T 0V528`

---

In summary: Is this JPEG recoverable?

Comment: It's recoverable if you can recover it. I'd investigate how this got corrupted. Bit-flip error? Truncation? Missing bytes? Once you've identified the problem you could try repairing it.

Comment: I have tried a professional software and it doesn't recover the file. So I doubt it is easy for you to just go and recover it when a dedicated software to do is not able to do it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

The approach used to get this back was more luck than judgement.  I think I can explain, though be aware it involves a hex editor...

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) for the syntax of a JPEG file explains that it is made up of a series of *segments* each started by a two byte marker - `0xFF` and another byte to indicate the type of segment.

The hope was that it was just the Huffman table segment of the file that was wrong - as suggested by the error message.  Without needing to understand what a Huffman table is, it was enough to see that the same section on Wikipedia explains it is a `0xFF` `0xC4` marker for a Huffman table segment.

Further down the page, it mentions:

> The JPEG standard provides general-purpose Huffman tables; encoders
>   may also choose to generate Huffman tables...

Opening up a few other JPEG files found what looks like a standard set of 4 consecutive Huffman table segments - each starting with that `0xFF` `0xC4` marker.  The sample `corrupt.jpg` however just had one Huffman table - from position `0x00c8` to `0x02bc` below.

(Both contain that `&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz` sequence you mentioned in their Huffman tables.  In the corrupt file it appears twice in that single Huffman table, in the 'more conventional' JPEGs it appears in the second and fourth Huffman tables.)

From there, the fixed image is a copy and paste of the standard 4 Huffman tables, in place of that range of bytes in `corrupt.jpg` - now from `0x00c8` to `0x0278` in the fixed file.

Because the JPEG format is based around scanning for segments between those `0xff` markers, you can just swap out the Huffman segments - there are no other pointers in the file to worry about.  As you said, the rest of the file looked like a plausible JPEG.

---

Summary of the steps taken:

- Hex search the `corrupt.jpg` for `FF C4` and note the offset
- Hex search for the next `FF`.  If it's another `FF C4` (so a second Huffman table) keep going
- Delete the content from the first `FF C4` (included) up to but not including the next `FF`
- Instead replace it with the 'standard 4 Huffman tables'.  These are the bytes in the last sample below, or can be copied from `0x00c8` to `0x0278` in the fixed file

---

Corrupt Huffman table:

```
0000-00d0:  xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx-ff c4 01 a2-00 00 01 05  !....... ........
0000-00e0:  01 01 01 01-01 01 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 02  ........ ........
0000-00f0:  03 04 05 06-07 08 09 0a-0b 01 00 03-01 01 01 01  ........ ........
0000-0100:  0c 10 0d 0b-0c 0f 0c 09-0a 0e 13 0e-0f 10 11 12  ........ ........
0000-0110:  12 12 0b 0d-13 15 13 11-15 10 11 12-11 01 03 03  ........ ........
0000-0120:  03 04 04 04-08 04 04 08-11 0b 0a 0b-11 11 11 11  ........ ........
0000-0130:  11 11 11 11-11 11 11 11-11 11 11 11-11 11 11 11  ........ ........
0000-0140:  11 11 11 11-11 11 11 11-11 11 11 11-11 11 11 11  ........ ........
0000-0150:  01 01 01 01-01 00 00 00-00 00 00 01-02 03 04 05  ........ ........
0000-0160:  06 07 08 09-0a 0b 10 00-02 01 03 03-02 04 03 05  ........ ........
0000-0170:  05 04 04 00-00 01 7d 01-02 03 00 04-11 05 12 21  ......}. .......!
0000-0180:  31 41 06 13-51 61 07 22-71 14 32 81-91 a1 08 23  1A..Qa." q.2....#
0000-0190:  42 b1 c1 15-52 d1 f0 24-33 62 72 82-09 0a 16 17  B...R..$ 3br.....
0000-01a0:  18 19 1a 25-26 27 28 29-2a 34 35 36-37 38 39 3a  ...%&'() *456789:
0000-01b0:  43 44 45 46-47 48 49 4a-53 54 55 56-57 58 59 5a  CDEFGHIJ STUVWXYZ
0000-01c0:  63 64 65 66-67 68 69 6a-73 74 75 76-77 78 79 7a  cdefghij stuvwxyz
0000-01d0:  83 84 85 86-87 88 89 8a-92 93 94 95-96 97 98 99  ........ ........
0000-01e0:  9a a2 a3 a4-a5 a6 a7 a8-a9 aa b2 b3-b4 b5 b6 b7  ........ ........
0000-01f0:  b8 b9 ba c2-c3 c4 c5 c6-c7 c8 c9 ca-d2 d3 d4 d5  ........ ........
0000-0200:  d6 d7 d8 d9-da e1 e2 e3-e4 e5 e6 e7-e8 e9 ea f1  ........ ........
0000-0210:  f2 f3 f4 f5-f6 f7 f8 f9-fa 11 00 02-01 02 04 04  ........ ........
0000-0220:  03 04 07 05-04 04 00 01-02 77 00 01-02 03 11 04  ........ .w......
0000-0230:  05 21 31 06-12 41 51 07-61 71 13 22-32 81 08 14  .!1..AQ. aq."2...
0000-0240:  42 91 a1 b1-c1 09 23 33-52 f0 15 62-72 d1 0a 16  B.....#3 R..br...
0000-0250:  24 34 e1 25-f1 17 18 19-1a 26 27 28-29 2a 35 36  $4.%.... .&'()*56
0000-0260:  37 38 39 3a-43 44 45 46-47 48 49 4a-53 54 55 56  789:CDEF GHIJSTUV
0000-0270:  57 58 59 5a-63 64 65 66-67 68 69 6a-73 74 75 76  WXYZcdef ghijstuv
0000-0280:  77 78 79 7a-82 83 84 85-86 87 88 89-8a 92 93 94  wxyz.... ........
0000-0290:  95 96 97 98-99 9a a2 a3-a4 a5 a6 a7-a8 a9 aa b2  ........ ........
0000-02a0:  b3 b4 b5 b6-b7 b8 b9 ba-c2 c3 c4 c5-c6 c7 c8 c9  ........ ........
0000-02b0:  ca d2 d3 d4-d5 d6 d7 d8-d9 da e2 e3-e4 e5 e6 e7  ........ ........
0000-02c0:  e8 e9 ea f2-f3 f4 f5 f6-f7 f8 f9 fa-xx xx xx xx  ........ ........
```

Then the next two bytes are `ff dd` for the start of the next segment:

```
0000-02c0:  xx xx xx xx-xx xx xx xx-xx xx xx xx-ff dd 00 04  ........ ........
```

This was replaced with the standard 4 general-purpose Huffman tables instead - look for the `ff c4` markers:

```
0000-00d0:  xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx-ff c4 00 1f-00 00 01 05  !....... ........
0000-00e0:  01 01 01 01-01 01 00 00-00 00 00 00-00 00 01 02  ........ ........
0000-00f0:  03 04 05 06-07 08 09 0a-0b ff c4 00-b5 10 00 02  ........ ........
0000-0100:  01 03 03 02-04 03 05 05-04 04 00 00-01 7d 01 02  ........ .....}..
0000-0110:  03 00 04 11-05 12 21 31-41 06 13 51-61 07 22 71  ......!1 A..Qa."q
0000-0120:  14 32 81 91-a1 08 23 42-b1 c1 15 52-d1 f0 24 33  .2....#B ...R..$3
0000-0130:  62 72 82 09-0a 16 17 18-19 1a 25 26-27 28 29 2a  br...... ..%&'()*
0000-0140:  34 35 36 37-38 39 3a 43-44 45 46 47-48 49 4a 53  456789:C DEFGHIJS
0000-0150:  54 55 56 57-58 59 5a 63-64 65 66 67-68 69 6a 73  TUVWXYZc defghijs
0000-0160:  74 75 76 77-78 79 7a 83-84 85 86 87-88 89 8a 92  tuvwxyz. ........
0000-0170:  93 94 95 96-97 98 99 9a-a2 a3 a4 a5-a6 a7 a8 a9  ........ ........
0000-0180:  aa b2 b3 b4-b5 b6 b7 b8-b9 ba c2 c3-c4 c5 c6 c7  ........ ........
0000-0190:  c8 c9 ca d2-d3 d4 d5 d6-d7 d8 d9 da-e1 e2 e3 e4  ........ ........
0000-01a0:  e5 e6 e7 e8-e9 ea f1 f2-f3 f4 f5 f6-f7 f8 f9 fa  ........ ........
0000-01b0:  ff c4 00 1f-01 00 03 01-01 01 01 01-01 01 01 01  ........ ........
0000-01c0:  00 00 00 00-00 00 01 02-03 04 05 06-07 08 09 0a  ........ ........
0000-01d0:  0b ff c4 00-b5 11 00 02-01 02 04 04-03 04 07 05  ........ ........
0000-01e0:  04 04 00 01-02 77 00 01-02 03 11 04-05 21 31 06  .....w.. .....!1.
0000-01f0:  12 41 51 07-61 71 13 22-32 81 08 14-42 91 a1 b1  .AQ.aq." 2...B...
0000-0200:  c1 09 23 33-52 f0 15 62-72 d1 0a 16-24 34 e1 25  ..#3R..b r...$4.%
0000-0210:  f1 17 18 19-1a 26 27 28-29 2a 35 36-37 38 39 3a  .....&'( )*56789:
0000-0220:  43 44 45 46-47 48 49 4a-53 54 55 56-57 58 59 5a  CDEFGHIJ STUVWXYZ
0000-0230:  63 64 65 66-67 68 69 6a-73 74 75 76-77 78 79 7a  cdefghij stuvwxyz
0000-0240:  82 83 84 85-86 87 88 89-8a 92 93 94-95 96 97 98  ........ ........
0000-0250:  99 9a a2 a3-a4 a5 a6 a7-a8 a9 aa b2-b3 b4 b5 b6  ........ ........
0000-0260:  b7 b8 b9 ba-c2 c3 c4 c5-c6 c7 c8 c9-ca d2 d3 d4  ........ ........
0000-0270:  d5 d6 d7 d8-d9 da e2 e3-e4 e5 e6 e7-e8 e9 ea f2  ........ ........
0000-0280:  f3 f4 f5 f6-f7 f8 f9 fa-xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx  ........ .....(..
```

Comment: That's very good news, thanks.  As I understand it, a Huffman table is the key to decompress the image, so it does feel surprising that the alternative table was compatible.  Hopefully we'll hear more on this thread about how often this works.